# Making Large IndexedDB Persistent in Browser

Tags: sql-server, html, browser, local-storage, indexeddb

I am looking at making a LOB html5 web application. The main part we are trying to accomplish is to make the application offline capable. This will mean taking a large chunk of SQL data from the server and storing it in the browser. This will need to be living in the browser for quite a while, dont want to have to continuously refresh it everytime the browser is closed and reopened.

We are looking at storing the data inside the client in indexedDB but I read that indexedDB is stored in temporary storage so the lifetime of it cannot be relied on. Does anyone know of any strategies on prolonging its lifetime? Also we will be pulling down massive chunks of data so 1-5mb storage might not suffice what we require.

My current thought is to somewhat store it down to the browser storage using html5 storage API's and hydrate it into the indexedDb as it's required. Just need to make sure we can grow the storage limit to whatever we need.

Any advice on how we approach this?

Comment: sorry, acronym for Line of Business, i.e. Enterprise app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are looking at storing the data inside the client in indexedDB but I read that indexedDB is stored in temporary storage so the lifetime of it cannot be relied on.

That is technically true but in practice I've never seen the browser actually delete data. More common if you're storing a lot of data, you will hit quota limits which are annoying and sometimes inconsistent/buggy.

Regardless, you shouldn't rely on data in IndexedDB always being there forever, because users can always delete data, have their computers break without backups, etc.

Comment: Hi Dumbmatter, thanks for the response. I'm not too phased if the user's computer break or delete data, that will be the 5% case. I want to make sure the 95% normal day to day case is handled and we can store a large chunk of indexedDb data down to the browser. If the data does get blown away in the 5% case we will just have to call back up to the server to refresh it.

Comment: Then you're probably fine with IndexedDB, just beware of how the quota.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Chrome extension, you can [enable unlimited storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions). I've successfully stored several thousand large text documents persistently in indexedDB using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly question to add, but can you access the storage area outside of the browser? For instance, if I did not want to have a huge lag when my app starts up and loads a bunch of data, could I make an external app to "refresh" the local data so that when the browser starts, it is ready to rock and roll?

I assume the answer here will be no, but I had to ask.

Has anyone worked around this for large data sets? For instance loading in one tab and working in another? Chrome extension to load, but access via the app?